# Adding an array value to an array retrieved using $.serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, checkbox

There are checkboxes, which belong to Form A:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="item-selector" name="item[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="item-selector" name="item[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="item-selector" name="item[]" value="3" />
<!-- etc. -->
```

Then I have Form B that needs the checkbox values from Form A. Form A might have other input fields too, but I'm not interested in those. I only care about `$('input.item-selector')`. I'm going about it like this:

```
var postData = $('#form-a').serializeArray();
var items = $('.item-selector:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();

if(items.length > 0) {
    postData.push({name: 'itemId', value: items});
}
```

But this way of adding stuff to the `postData` doesn't seem to work, because the PHP script I send the form to can not find the `itemId`. Interestingly this does work:

```
postData.push(name: 'aName', value: 'notAnArrayButAStringValue');
```

I also tried a couple of solutions like this one: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject but the problem with them is that, while they otherwise work fine, for some reason if there are checkboxes in Form B, the checkbox values of Form B are parsed incorrectly and result in null values and loss of data. That would look like this:

```
var postData = $(this.form).serializeObject();    
var items = $('.item-selector:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
if(items.length > 0) {
    postData.itemId = items;
}
```

Using JSON.stringify revealed the object structure to be like this:

```
{
    "name":"Simon J. Kok",
    "address_id":"39669",
    "email":"*****",
    "content_id":"21921",
    "client_id":"42101",
    "is_ebill":["","1"], <-- this is a checked checkbox
    "is_banned":"", <-- this is an unchecked checkbox
    "button":"save"
}
```

The checkboxes in Form B look like

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="is_ebill" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="is_banned" />
```

So what I need is either some insight on how to add the checkboxes from Form A to the `$.serializeArray()` result array -OR- a way to solve the issue of a checked checkbox returning an array when using Ben Alman's plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I kinda answered my own question already when I asked it. I used `JSON.Stringify` to output the JSON formatted string of what `$.serializeArray()` returned and it became apparent what the structrure needed to work. So here is how to add array values one by one to an array retrieved using `$.serializeArray()`:

```
var items = $('.item-selector:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();

$.each(items, function(i, v){
    postData.push({name: 'itemId[]', value: v});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. First it requires a hidden field in `form-b`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="itemId" name="itemId" value="" />
```

This would be populated with the `item-selector` data when the form is submitted:

```
$('#form-b').on('submit', function() {
    var checkedValues = [];
    $('.item-selector:checked').each(function() {
        checkedValues.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('#itemId').val(checkedValues.join(','));
    console.debug('Form B data:', $('#form-b').serializeArray());
});
```

Adjust the syntax to suit your idiom. Here's a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/12evxfvc/